# Passing the same array between functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, greedy, kruskals-algorithm

I am writing a C++ program for my class that calculates the MST (minimum spanning tree) for a set of inputted edges. I have written a few functions up to this point and have gotten stuck trying to pass an array which holds the "edges" of the minimum spanning tree. How do I pass this array from the `readGraph` function to `insertEdge` function?

When I try to use '&' the compiler shows this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '4' to 'void insertEdge(int, int, int, int*)'|
```

[Instructions for the assignment](http://cs.ecu.edu/~karl/2530/spr18/Assn/Assn5/assn5.html)

```
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdio>
#include "equiv.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// Edge structure which creates 3 integer variables(vert1, vert2, weight)
// and uses a constructor to initialize these variables.
// "vert1" & "vert2" hold 2 vertex numbers and "weight" holds the weight of a edge.

struct Edge
{
    int vert1;
    int vert2;
    int weight;

   Edge() : vert1(0), vert2(0), weight(0)
   {
   }
};
const int maxEdges = 100;
struct Graph
{
    int vertGraph;
    int edgeGraph;
    int edgeArray [maxEdges];
    int physicalSizeArray;
   Graph(int nv) : vertGraph(0), edgeGraph(0), edgeArray(), physicalSizeArray(0)
   {
   }
};
// insertEdge(u, v, w, g) inserts an edge of weight w between vertices
// u and v into graph g.
//
// If there is not enough room in g to add the edge, then
// insertEdge does nothing.
void insertEdge(int u,int v,int w,int g[])
{
    int arrayPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxEdges; i++) 
    {
        if (g[i] == 0) {
            if(arrayPosition == 0)
            {
                g[i] = u;
                arrayPosition++;
            }
           else if(arrayPosition == 1)
           {
                g[i] = w;
                arrayPosition++;
           }
           else if(arrayPosition == 2)
           {
                g[i] = v;
                break;
           }
        }
    }
}
void readGraph(int G[])
{
    Edge p1;
    bool nextEdge = true;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of vertices: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Enter two vertices separated by a space and followed by a weight for edge: ";
    while(nextEdge)
    {
        cin >> (p1.vert1, p1.vert2, p1.weight);
        insertEdge(p1.vert1,p1.vert2,p1.weight,G);
        if(p1.vert1 == 0)
        {
            nextEdge = false;
        }
   }
}

int main()
{
    int arrayTest[20];
    readGraph(&arrayTest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @the_storyteller I tried that but the compiler shows this .........error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '4' to 'void insertEdge(int, int, int, int*)'|

Comment: @the_storyteller are you sure? if you do that aren't you just dereferencing the pointer to the first element i.e getting the first element? I would argue that when invoking readgraph the OP should send `readGraph(arrayTest)` instead of `readGraph(&arrayTest)`

Comment: You should ask your professor if you can use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to pass an array to a function as a parameter:

```
1. void function(int* param)

2. void function(int param[20]) 

3. void function(int param[])
```

All these three possible declarations produce similar results, since all of them are telling the compiler that an integer pointer is going to be received as parameter of the function.

> How do I pass this array from the readGraph function to insertEdge
>   function?

```
readGraph(arrayTest);
```

You should not pass the memory address of the array, but the array itself, i.e. a pointer to the array by specifying the array's name without an index.

Be also aware that C++ performs no bounds checking for the formal parameters, so better go for an `std::array` or `std::vector` than a `c-array`.